# MapBox GeoJSON clear all markers?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I would like to update my map with "new" markers. So reset all visible markers first. Ill read my markers by geoJSON by Ajax with:

```
   $.ajax({
        url: 'dashboard/geoJSON',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(geojson) {
            var locations = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);
            locations.setGeoJSON(geojson); 
            // reset?

         }
    });
```

Ill tried with:

```
L.mapbox.featureLayer().clearLayers();
```

To reset before adding all new markers, but it is not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ill found a solution:

```
success: function(geojson) {

            markers.forEach(function(entry) {
                map.removeLayer(entry);
            });

            locations = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);
            locations.on('layeradd', function (e) {
                var marker = e.layer;
                markers.push(marker);
            });

            locations.setGeoJSON(geojson);
```

So ill use the 'layeradd' method to manually push my array, and then remove all before setting new ones.

Answer (score 0):

You should clear the layers from the `map` object, not `featureLayers`, where the `layer` variable is the layer with all your markers:

```js
map.removeLayer(layer);
```

Think of the global `L` object as a 'generator' of sorts. You can chain off it to create maps, layers, markers, and more. You'll *attach* these to a particular map by chaining off the map.

Comment: Thanks - but ill need an array with all markers - how can ill reset all layers without storing them first in an array? Because i have no foreach loop to add each marker to the map, ill just set it with:                 var locations = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);
                locations.setGeoJSON(geojson);